# Jenkins Subversion Multibranch pipeline cannot find pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to setup a Multibranch Project in Jenkins that uses Subversion. I provided a Subversion URL with trunk, tags and branches folder for example http:///mysvn/mysvnproject

Branch Indexing Log is successful, shows message similar to

> Checking candidate branch /mysvnproject/trunk@181182 Met
>   criteria Scheduled build for branch: trunk Finished: SUCCESS

This indicates that Jenkins is able to find my `Jenkinsfile`. When I remove this  file, branching indexing fails.

When I start a build it fails with message similar to

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM in this directory
>   (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myproject_trunk-2VTWI7CSGJKGC5PD7FA5VNZ27SJLDDFKIGYZO5K5N23XXZU7MEJA).
>   Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help
>   1]

When I check the workspace on the server, I can see three directories are created

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  6 25 okt 11:56 myproject_trunk-2VTWI7CSGJKGC5PD7FA5VNZ27SJLDDFKIGYZO5K5N23XXZU7MEJA
drwxr-xr-x 5 jenkins jenkins 78 25 okt 11:56 myproject_trunk-2VTWI7CSGJKGC5PD7FA5VNZ27SJLDDFKIGYZO5K5N23XXZU7MEJA@script
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  6 26 okt 07:08 myproject_trunk-2VTWI7CSGJKGC5PD7FA5VNZ27SJLDDFKIGYZO5K5N23XXZU7MEJA@tmp
```

- This first directory is empty and is not a Subversion working copy.
- The second directory (that ends with `@script`) is a Subversion working copy and it contains the contents of the `trunk` and so the `pom.xml`.
- The last directory is empty and also not a Subversion working copy.

Jenkins tries to run the build in a empty directory

```
#!groovy

node ('master') {

  stage 'Compile'
  env.PATH = "${tool 'Maven 3.2.5'}/bin:${env.PATH}"

  sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests' 
}
```

A workaround for this issue is to cd into the script directory in each `sh` for example with

```
sh 'cd ../*@script && mvn install -DskipTests'
```

But this shouldn't be necessary..?

Why is this not working right away?

Answer (score 0):

Putting `checkout scm` in your Jenkinsfile will fill your empty pipeline directory with the source.

Comment: I am so confused as to how my JENKINSFILE could already be running, yet the WORKSPACE doesn't have the branch cloned already. But indeed, this fixes it.